# Does this guarantee invertibility in higher-dimensional functions?

Tags: monotone-functions

Let $f(\mathbf{x}):\mathbb{R}^N\mapsto\mathbb{R}^N$ be structured as:

$$
f(\mathbf{x})= \left[\begin{matrix}
f_1(x_1,...,x_N) \\
f_2(x_1,...,x_N) \\
\vdots \\
f_N(x_1,...,x_N) \\
\end{matrix}\right]
$$

where each $f_n(x_1,...,x_N):\mathbb{R}^N\mapsto\mathbb{R}$ is monotone in $x_{n}$, that is to say, $\partial_{x_n}f_n > 0$ for all $n=1,\dots,N$.

Does this monotonicity property suffice to ensure that $f(\mathbf{x})$ is invertible / bijective for any $\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^N$? If not, why?

Comment: I think you should easily be able to find a counterexample where all the $f_i$ are the same function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take for example $f_1=f_2=x_1+x_2$. This satisfies $\partial_{x_1}f_1=\partial_{x_2}f_2=1$ but is not invertible anywhere.

What you need is instead that the determinant of the matrix of partial derivatives is non-zero. See [Inverse function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem).

Comment: I'm sure they meant $\partial_{x_i} f_j \gt 0$, but your example still works.

Answer (score 1):

$f(x,y) =(2x+3y, 2x+3y)$ is a simple counterexample.